# Creating a new text file with python is not happening unless i press ENTER in shell window

Tags: python, python-requests, wxpython, python-3.6

Am new to python and am working on a script that take a sentence from a text file, check its spelling and return the result to a new text file. When I run the script, the shell window open and the new text file is not creating unless i press ENTER in the shell window. I want the creation to happend directly without pressing ENTER. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
import sys
import nltk
import enchant
import os
from pathlib import Path
my_file=Path('C:/Users/HP/Documents/result.txt')
if my_file.is_file():
    os.remove("C:/Users/HP/Documents/result.txt")
    save_path='C:/Users/HP/Documents'
    name_of_file=input("result.txt")
    completeName=os.path.join(save_path,name_of_file+"result.txt")
    file1=open(completeName,"w")
    with open ("C:/Users/HP/Documents/test.txt") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n','')
    from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
    chkr=SpellChecker("fr")
    chkr.set_text(data)
    for err in chkr:
        var=("ERROR:",err.word)
        file1.write(str(var))
    file1.close()
else:
    save_path='C:/Users/HP/Documents'
    name_of_file=input("result.txt")
    completeName=os.path.join(save_path,name_of_file+"result.txt")
    file1=open(completeName,"w")
    with open ("C:/Users/HP/Documents/test.txt") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n','')
    from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
    chkr=SpellChecker("fr")
    chkr.set_text(data)
    for err in chkr:
        var=("ERROR:",err.word)
        file1.write(str(var))
    file1.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `input`:

```
name_of_file="result.txt"
```

`input` is needed if you want user to enter the string from keyboard. Hence, your program waits for ENTER key to be pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the calls to `input()` which require the user to press enter to terminate the input, if any.

```
name_of_file=input("result.txt")
```

If the user just presses enter then `name_of_file` will be the empty string. However, since this user input is used to construct a path to a writable file, you should be careful of this entry as the user could type in something unexpected, e.g. `../`, and the resulting output file would then be `C:/Users/HP/Documents/../result.txt` which might unintendedly (or perhaps intentionally) overwrite a different file.